# How to speed up retrieval of a large number of small files from HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, parquet

I am trying to copy a parquet file from a hadoop cluster to an edge node, using `hadoop fs -get`. The parquet file is around 2.4gb in size but is made up of thousands of files, each around 2kb in size. This process is taking forever.

Is there something I can do to speed up the process, maybe increase the concurrency?

I do not own the cluster and cannot make configuration changes to it.

Comment: Do you have one `.parquet` file or thousands of 2kb `.parquet` files?

Answer (score 1):

You can try distcp rather than using -get command, provided your cluster where you are running the command has MapReduce support

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html#Basic_Usage